# Intellij gui designer open a form on other form as a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij IDEA GUI Designer to create a java swing GUI.

I'v a Frame, created using Design Form, that has a card layout, and i want my cards to be other Design Forms.

I'm able to use cards created inside my Frame Form, and custom cards (100% coded), but i cant figure out how to use other Forms created on GUI Form as Card.

for example i have a JPanel (empty) that is one of my cards (otherJpanel), and i do this:

```
private void createUIComponents() {
    otherJpanel = new teste();
}
```

if teste is a custom 100% coded Jlabel it works, but if its a GUI Form (that extends JPanel) it shows nothing.

Thanks for the help and have a good year ;)

Comment: *"..but if its a GUI Form (that extends JPanel)"* Does it have a size greater than 0x0?  Set a background color for it.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The JPanel from GUI From has a button, so the size is not 0.

Comment: *"..the size is not 0."* Prove it by posting an MCVE.